# How do I save the current HEAD so I can check it back out in the same way later?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I want to do:

```sh
current_state="$(git something-or-another)"
```

and then, later:

```sh
git checkout "$current_state"
```

and get back to whatever situation I had originally, whether it was a branch, detached head, or whatever. (I don't need to worry about uncommitted changes; the working directory will be clean during both halves of the operation.) I'm also open to other commands besides `checkout` to achieve this, but I would strongly prefer something that can be saved in a string, or failing that, a commit or ref.

Things I've tried so far:

- **`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`:** works when a branch is checked out, but returns `HEAD` if detached, which is no good for getting back *what* was detached.
- **`git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD`:** returns `refs/heads/<branch>` which gets interpreted by `git checkout` as an instruction to detach rather than check out the branch. Also, on orphan branches (i.e. branches with no commits yet) fails with `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`
- **`git symbolic-ref HEAD`:** Same problem with `refs/heads/`; also, fails with an error if head is detached.
- **`git symbolic-ref -q HEAD || git rev-parse HEAD`:** Works when detached, but still has same problem as above with `refs/heads/` causing detachment.
- **`(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD || git rev-parse HEAD) | sed 's%^refs/heads/%%'`:** this is the closest I've come, and it *seems* to work, but it feels incredibly hacky.
- **`cp "$(git rev-parse --git-dir)"/HEAD{,.bak}` plus `git checkout -- .`:** this also seems to work, but if anything seems even hackier than the previous option.

Am I missing something? How can I easily string-ify and restore HEAD, in all of its possible states?

Answer (score 1):

To get the current branch name, use `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`.  If this produces an error, you are in detached HEAD mode; remember that fact and run `git rev-parse HEAD` to get the hash ID.

To return to where you were:

```
if $was_on_branch; then
    git switch $branch_name
else
    git switch --detach $hash
fi
```

where `$hash` is the saved hash ID, `$branch_name` is the saved branch name, and `$was_on_branch` is the status flag.  (Use `git checkout` with the same arguments if you have an older Git that lacks `git switch`.)

There is one mode this does not cover: if you're on an *unborn* branch, the symbolic ref lookup will *succeed* but the branch does not yet exist so the attempt to switch back will fail.  This particular case probably should not be handled in general, but if you want to handle it, note that this is the only case where `git symbolic-ref` succeeds, yet `git rev-parse HEAD` fails.

---

In general, if you're considering doing this, you might also consider using `git worktree add` instead.

Comment: Ugh, sounds like the TLDR is “no, you have to roll your own.” I guess in the case of an unborn branch I need to save that as a *third* option (in addition to 'branch' and 'detach') and do `git checkout --orphan <branch>` in that situation?

Comment: (Agreed that `git worktree` is a good solution to the XY problem implied by this post, but in my case I'm using this to prototype an alternative to `git stash`, which is why I'm doing weird things with git internals.)

Comment: Yes, the orphan branch case requires a `git checkout --orphan` or `git switch --orphan`. Note that the latter does a `git read-tree --empty -u` as a side effect, while the former doesn't (an odd incongruity in the new `git switch` although I think one can easily argue that checkout's failure to do that was a bug—but there's no *option*...).

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @torek's excellent answer explaining all of the different cases, I've produced the following bash functions which can serialize the state of HEAD to a string and then apply it later.

I tend to agree with them that this is probably something you should avoid doing if possible, but if you can't then this should get the job done:

```sh
# Serialize HEAD into a string that can be stored, passed around, etc.
# and later used with the below function to get back that state.
git_serialize_head() {
    if branch="$(git symbolic-ref --quiet --short HEAD)"; then
        if git rev-parse --quiet --verify HEAD > /dev/null; then
            # On a branch
            echo "branch $branch"
        else
            # On an orphaned/unborn branch (have name, but no commits)
            echo "orphan $branch"
        fi
    else
        # Detached head
        echo "detach $(git rev-parse HEAD)"
    fi
}

# Take a string from the function above and apply it to the git repository.
git_checkout_serialized_head() {
    type="${1%% *}" # Remove everything from first space to end of string
    value="${1#* }" # Remove everything from start of string to first space
    
    if [[ "$type" == "branch" ]]; then
        git checkout "$value"
    elif [[ "$type" == "orphan" ]]; then
        # Note - though the branch was unborn when we serialized it, it may not
        # be any longer. Since `checkout --orphan` will complain if the branch
        # already exists, in this scenario check out that branch instead.
        # 
        # We still need to know if it was an orphan branch at serialization time,
        # though, because if it *wasn't* that means it was deleted in between
        # serialization and restoration, and the user probably doesn't want it to
        # come back as a new root in their repo. (The unqualified `git checkout`
        # in the type==branch case above will produce an error for us in this
        # situation.)
        if git rev-parse --quiet --verify "$value" > /dev/null; then
            # Not an orphan any more, check out normally
            git checkout "$value"
        else
            # Still an orphan, check out as such
            git checkout --orphan "$value"
        fi
    elif [[ "$type" == "detach" ]]; then
        git checkout --detach "$value"
    else
        echo "Unknown checkout type in serialized HEAD: $type" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

Comment: BTW, if you have `local` I like to mark each of the local variables. You can also use `set $1` to split at whitespace and then use `$1` as the type and `$2` as the value. Branch names are not allowed to have whitespace, and hash IDs don't, so this should be safe.